# I can't send SMS with Twilio and Aloha library

Tags: php, laravel, sms, try-catch, twilio

I'm using Laravel 5.1 and I want to send SMS messages so I installed Aloha library:
https://github.com/aloha/laravel-twilio

I edited .env file with :

```
TWILIO_SID=AC7556934234234234234uuuuuuuuuu3
TWILIO_TOKEN=ca8xxxxxb9b60e66666666666666d355cfe315
TWILIO_FROM=+555555555555
```

Now I try to send a SMS with code:

```
...
use Twilio;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Aloha\Twilio\TwilioInterface;
use Services_Twilio_RestException;

class AdminController extends Controller {

    public function send() {
        try {
            Twilio::message('+77777777777', 'test test test');
        } catch (\Services_Twilio_RestException $e) {
            dd($e);
        }
```

When I run function `send()` nothing happens (blank white screen) - no error with catch{} but also I don't receive SMS. When I look at Twilio SMS log there is nothing also.

How I can get an error message?
WHy this code doesn't send a message?

Comment: Your code example doesn't close its brackets fully, is that the case in the actual app? Do you return or render anything from your `send` method?

Answer (score 2):

Avid Twilio user here. I would recommend using Twilio's native PHP SDK over aloha/twilio. By default, I believe aloha/twilio pulls in twilio/sdk as it depends upon it, but I would remove aloha/twilio and just use twilio/sdk.

```
composer require twilio/sdk
```

I would then recommend creating a Twilio class inside say Services/Twilio.php where you can inject Twilio's client, create a new instance and instantiate it with your twilio config data. In this Service class, you could now put all of your Twilio methods like sendSMS(), sendMMS(), validatePhoneNumber(), etc and have access to them by injecting the new Twilio service class into your controller's constructor.

It might look like this:

*Note that my implementation of sendSMS() uses a MessagingServiceSid and not a from number. You can replace 'messagingServiceSid' with 'from' if you are not utilizing a Twilio CoPilot Messaging Service in their platform.*

**Services/Twilio.php**

```
namespace App\Services;

use Twilio\Rest\Client;

class Twilio
{


    /**
     * @var Client
     */
    protected $twilio;


    public function __construct() {
        try {
            $this->twilio = new Client(config('twilio.SID'), config('twilio.TOKEN'));
        }
        catch (\Exception $e) {
            //do something with the exception, client could not be instantiated.
        }
    }

//My sendSMS allows for the passing of an array in the $to argument, letting you send to
//multiple numbers (or just one)
    public function sendSMS($to, $message)
    {
        if (is_array($to)) {
            foreach($to as $value) {
                $this->twilio->messages->create($value, ['messagingServiceSid' => config('twilio.MESSAGING_SERVICE_SID'), 'body' => $message]);
            }
            return true;
        }
        $this->twilio->messages->create($to, ['messagingServiceSid' => config('twilio.MESSAGING_SERVICE_SID'), 'body' => $message]);
    }
}
```

**AdminController.php**

```
use App\Services\Twilio;

class AdminController extends Controller {

    protected $twilio;
    public function __construct(Twilio $twilio) 
    {
       $this->twilio = $twilio;
    }

    public function index()
{
$this->twilio->sendSMS('5551234567', 'Test message');
return 'Message was sent.';
}

}
```

If you implement Twilio in this way, you will be able to use any of the Twilio logic inside your controller without having to repeatedly create a new Twilio client or pass any of the config data.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Twilio web console and try sending messages. It typically gives a message or error code if a message is not sent successfully.

I have faced issues with Twilio not sending messages due to Country specific telecom policy for not accepting messages from unsolicited users/accounts.

Comment: I think its not possbile to send SMS from Twilio backofice

Comment: You can test out Twilio API endpoints in the Twilio console using the [API explorer](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/debugging-tools#test-with-the-api-explorer).